# Disable multiple click on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to disable multiple click  on a button. The code is as below

```
<div class="pull-right"> 
  <input type="button" name="Submit" class="btn btn-success" id="anext" value='<s:text name="generic.next.caps"></s:text>' onclick='showPopUp();'/>
</div>

<div class="pull-right">
  <s:submit type="submit" name="Submit" cssClass="btn btn-success" id="acontd" value="%{getText('generic.continue.caps')}" action="ActionName"/>
</div>
```

My solution:

```
$("anext").click(function(){
    $("aptcnext").prop("disabled", true);
});
$("acontd").click(function(){
    $("aptccontd").prop("disabled", true);
});
```

However, this is not working. Could anyone help me this?

Comment: What does "not working" mean exactly? What is your expected result and what is the actual result?

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead

```js
$("input[type='submit']").click(function() {
  $(this).prop("disabled", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pull-right">
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-success" id="anext" onclick='showPopUp();' />
</div>

<div class="pull-right">
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-success" id="acontd" action="ActionName" />
</div>
```

Comment: Keep your first solution as a fix for OP's code, and put the second(with `input[type='submit']`) as a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method to accept the click event only one time

```js
$(function () {
  $("#anext").one('click', function(e){
    alert('ok');
  });
  $("#acontd").one('click', function(){
    alert('ok');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="pull-right">
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-success" id="anext" onclick='showPopUp();' />
</div>

<div class="pull-right">
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" cssClass="btn btn-success" id="acontd" action="ActionName" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $('#disable').on('click', function(){
    $('#disable').attr("disabled", true);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="disable">Disable Me!</button>
<p>Hello</p>
```